# Json into EF with duplicates

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I have following sample JSON (simplified):

```
{
   "programmes":[
      {
             "programmeID":"163",
             "title":"Programme 1",
             "color":"#ff5f57",
             "moderators":[
                {
                   "moderatorID":"27",
                   "name":"Moderator 1",
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "programmeID":"153",
             "title":"Programme 2",
             "color":"#ff5f57",
             "moderators":[
                {
                   "moderatorID":"27",
                   "name":"Moderator 1",
                }
             ]
          },

       ]
}
```

I want to convert into following objects:

```
    public class Programme
    {
        [Key]
        public string programmeID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        //Navigational Property
        public virtual ICollection<Moderator> moderators { get; set; }
    }

    public class Moderator
    {
        [Key]
        public string moderatorID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        //Navigational Property
        public virtual ICollection<Programme> programmes { get; set; }
    }
```

Everything is fine, objects looks great, populated correctly, but when trying to save into db a get this error:

> The instance of entity type 'Moderator' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the key value '{moderatorID: 27}' is already
> being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
> entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This error happens when calling .Add with the list of Programmes:

```
List<Programme> programmes;
programmes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Programme>>(JSONcontent);
//... db init
db.AddRange(programmes);
```

I understand that there is a duplicity for Moderator (ID=27), but I think that it's quite a normal pattern in JSON. I can do some workaround, but wondering if there is any best practice how to handle this in EF directly?

Comment: You have to show the code are you trying to add to db

Comment: From what you wrote, the save appears to be trying to do an insert and not an update.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278581/saving-deserialized-json-objects-to-database-with-duplicate-child-entities

Comment: simplified code added, good point that it's not update, but insert. The problem is how to handle correctly.

Comment: Do you want insert only programme or the 2 entity? See this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not add children you are created from deserialization as an existed ones. One of the solutions is finding the existed children at first

```
List<Programme> programmes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Programme>>(JSONcontent);

foreach (var program in programmes)
{
var moderators=new List<Moderator>();
foreach (var moderator in program.moderators)
{
     var existingModerator=db.Moderators.FirstOrDefault(i=> 
                 i.moderatorId=moderator.moderatorId);
    moderators.Add(existingModerator);
}
  programm.moderators=moderators;
}
db.AddRange(programmes);
```

but I usually prefer to create an explicit class for many to many relations. It will make all your code much more simple.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "explicit class" as many:many table is generated by EF. I can see it the database.

Comment: @TomasSvestka  You can define ProgrammeModerator class manually

Comment: I can, but please how does it resolve issue with duplicity? Is there any trick to tell EF how to process such case?

Comment: @TomasSvestka Yes, in this case you can create ProgrammeModerator class and assign Programme and ModeratorId

Comment: And you mean, do it manually, right? that makes sense, thanks!